# How to build with Next + fetch() + .env?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, environment-variables, prisma

I'm quite sure the solution is quite obvious, but man... I'm looking all over the internet and I can't find how to solve this. Please treat me as a beginner hungry to learn!

I have an app using Next 14 (App Router) + Prisma. The app is running just fine in my local environment, the problems start when I run `npm run build`.  I start getting errors like `TypeError: fetch failed`  or even `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON` .

I presume it is an error with my api routes on build. I just can't find the right solution to that. Here's a simplified example of  my code.

**.env**

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

**data-fetchers.ts**

```
const url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL

...

async function getAllEvents() {
  console.log(">>>> NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL IS: ", url)
  const data = await fetch(url + "/api/events", {
    method: "GET",
    cache: "no-cache",
  })

  const events = await data.json()
  return events
}

...
```

**page.tsx**

```
import { getAllEvents } from "@/app/data-fetchers"

export default async function Events() {
  const events = await getAllEvents()

  return (
    <div >
        {events.map((event) => (
          <div>
            <p>{event.id}</p>
            <p>{event.name}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Once again, it is working perfectly in local. It's when I run `npm run build` that I get errors:
(I simplified the error log, let me know if more is needed)

```
   ▲ Next.js 14.1.0
   - Environments: .env.local, .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...
Compiler edge-server unexpectedly exited with code: null and signal: SIGTERM
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types    
 ✓ Collecting page data    
   Generating static pages (20/24) [  ==] 

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5419:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5390:27)
    at fullyReadBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1501:9)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async specConsumeBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5399:7)
    at async n (/.../.next/server/app/admin/page.js:5:2073)
    at async i (/.../.next/server/app/user/page.js:5:2639)

Error occurred prerendering page "/events". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

 ✓ Generating static pages (24/24) 

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /admin/page: /admin
        /events/page: /events
        /organizer/page: /organizer
        /user/page: /user
```

The `console.log()` in `data-fetchers.ts` prints `>>>> NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL IS: http://localhost:3000` in both local and build environment.

**Should I add another env variable for build? Am I using the wrong strategy here?**

I know I could also call prisma from the component itself instead of calling the api (which then calls prisma). But that seems to bring an whole new pack of problems and (for now) going through the API makes me feel safer about exposing too much. But hey, let me know if that's indeed the right strategy!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing your Github repository, I think the issue comes from using the fetch API in a Nodejs environment, which is experimental (I think at least for now). I tried using axios in the `getAllEvents()` function and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I use "/api/events" directly I get the error  `⨯ TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/events Cause: TypeError: Invalid URL`

I also don't believe it's an error in my endpoint because I'm getting all expected responses in development. I only get errors when I run build.

Comment: Do you have a Github repository? So I can give a closer look.

Comment: I have just checked the documentation and you're right! The fetch() really does give this error, but only when running on the server. I gave you the suggestion because I mainly use fetch() only on the client.

Comment: I do! Thanks! https://github.com/guisiebert/gopanda-tickets/blob/main/src/app/events/page.tsx // https://github.com/guisiebert/gopanda-tickets/blob/main/src/app/data-fetchers.ts // https://github.com/guisiebert/gopanda-tickets/blob/main/src/app/api/events/route.ts

Comment: Do you think I should try to run it all on the client? How far can I go to not expose more than I should?

Comment: In my opinion, you should fetch your data without the fetch call, because it will slow down your application. Fetching directly on the page (React Server Component) or in a lib function, would be the best option IMO.

Comment: I have updated my answer! Cheers from Brazil too :)

Comment: Cool. I'll try it out again with axios. Muito obrigado Nic!

Comment: No problem! De nada!